# ошибка при переходе в activity

Tags: android, android-studio

приложение вылетает при переходе на другое activity. Помогите пожалуйста
java class:

```
package edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    }
}
```

`xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.Activity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:text="okay"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
`
```

logcat:

```
2019-05-03 14:55:18.701 6125-6125/edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx, PID: 6125
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.Activity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2951)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:354)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:323)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:11)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
```

android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PocketSphinxActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Решение ищите в этой строчке: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. У вас что-то со стилями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение нужно искать в этой строчке: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. У вас что-то со стилями.

Добавьте а манифест на уровень application: `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

```
<application
.....
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
.....>
.......
</application>
```

а в стилях должно быть:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, где должны располагаться "стили" у меня эта конструкция подчеркивается красным

Comment: @ДимаК res/values/styles.xml и там вставляете участок со стилями